# Python: Is there syntax-level support for unpacking, from tuples, the arguments to an *anonymous* function?

Tags: python, lambda, coding-style, language-design, iterable-unpacking

Suppose we have the following:

```
args = (4,7,5)
def foo(a,b,c): return a*b%c
```

Python conveniently allows tuple unpacking:

```
foo(4,7,5)             # returns 3
foo(*args)             # returns foo(4,7,5), i.e. 3
```

So that we don't have to do this:

```
foo(t[0], t[1], t[2])  # a repulsive, verbose, and error-prone synonym
```

Now suppose we had a list of similar 3-tuples and wanted a list of `foo(t)` for each tuple `t`. There is "one obvious way to do it":

```
list(map(lambda t: foo(*t), listoftuples))
```

But now suppose `foo` is just a throw-away function. We don't want rubbish polluting our namespace. Let's sweep it under the rug of anonymity!:

```
list(map(lambda t: (lambda a, b, c: a*b%c)(*t), listoftuples))
```

Well, we now have nested lambdas. Sure, we can parse that. But we run the risk of being mistaken for a schemer who delights in constructing cryptic spells for the sole purpose of stumping those presumptuous enough to review our code.

Furthermore, this is kinda verbose for such a simple idea. This just does not seem pythonic. (In scala, the equivalent of that inner lambda is `(_*_%_)`, assuming context allows type inference. If this *was* pythonic, wouldn't it be similarly concise?).

We could remove that inner lambda this way:

```
list(map((lambda t: t[0] * t[1] % t[2]), listoftuples))
```

That's shorter, but repulsive. I have found that using magic numbers (rather than names) to refer to parameters tends to cause errors.

It would be great if it looked much more like this:

```
list(map((lambda a, b, c: a*b%c), listoftuples))
```

Of course, it couldn't be that. That's like trying to call `foo(args)`. We need an asterisk, so to speak. Here's one possible asterisk:

```
def unpackInto(func): return lambda t: func(*t)
```

It makes for pleasantly readable code:

```
list(map(unpackInto(lambda a, b, c: a*b%c), listoftuples))
```

But we'd have to import that from a personal module all the time. That's not suitable for collaboration, and it's kind of annoying for one-time use.

**TL;DR**

I want `unpackInto` to be part of the language. Is it already supported in syntax? In standard libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`starmap`! [It's in the itertools package](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap).

From my examples:

```
list(map(lambda t: foo(*t), listoftuples))
```

becomes

```
list(starmap(foo, listoftuples))
```

See why it's called starmap? And with anonymous functions:

```
def unpackInto(func): return lambda t: func(*t)
list(map(unpackInto(lambda a, b, c: a*b%c), listoftuples))
```

becomes

```
list(starmap(lambda a, b, c: a*b%c, listoftuples))
```

A simple four-letter prefix, `star`, is the "asterisk" I was looking for.

So, **yes**, there is standard library support for unpacking parameters from tuples into anonymous functions **but** only for map, via starmap.

**No**, there is no syntax-level support, **but** there *was* syntax level support in python 2. See Bakuriu's answer. The last would become:

```
list(map(lambda (a, b, c): a*b%c, listoftuples))
```

Which is even more concise. It's almost a shame it had to be [taken away](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

Then again, lambda is rarely as concise or readable as a list comprehension:

```
[a*b%c for a, b, c in listoftuples]
```

Comment: I wonder how I could forget that! Probably I was considering too much the syntactic aspect of your question...

Answer (score 6):

In python2 it *was* possible to use tuple-unpacking for this:

```
>>> def func((a,b,c)):
...     return a+b+c
... 
>>> func((1,2,3))
6
```

However this feature was *removed* in python3. See [PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/). The reasons why it was removed are:

- They are very difficult to introspect
- They don't introduce any functionality since you can create a function like:

  ```
  def func(a_b_c):
     a,b,c = a_b_c
  ```

  And achieve the same result
- They provided ugly error messages

With this removal python currently does *not* support what you want with any syntax nor any stdlib function.

Since this syntax was removed with a PEP I highly doubt that the core developers will accept your `unpack_into` function. *However* there may be a *small* chance to add something like that into the [`functools`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html) module which should contain this kind of things. You should probably ask to the python developers about this, but be sure to provide good arguments to support your request.

Comment: wow I read the question 10 times and was about to finally understand what OP wanted, but you beat me to it!

Comment: That is a cool way to implement it, by the way! I just tested it out with python2. I would use this all the time!

Comment: They don't introduce any functionality, but they trade a line of boiler plate for two parentheses. That's a bad argument. I could point at plenty of features that don't improve functionality!

Comment: @stewSquared Don't argue with me, argue with the core developers! The fact is: this feature wasn't used *at all*. I believe *no* standard library function *ever* used this, and even 3rd party code didn't use it. Most people don't even know you could do this. Thus the inconvenience of the extra line of code isn't noticeable in the big picture, while allowing them introduce significant complexity for introspection mechanisms, which are *much* more used.

Comment: @stewSquared: In general, Python shies away from doing things with special syntax.  You already were able to write a function to do what you want, so it's not clear what you think syntax will gain you, or why the language should have special syntax just for this particular case.

Comment: I was just pointing out that argument two from PEP3113 didn't make sense at face value. The decision is making a lot more sense to me -- I don't like a bloated syntax either. @BrenBarn For the most part, I was just curious whether the construct existed. It's interesting that it did at one point.

Comment: @stewSquared: Your development of the question paints you into the corner of trying to find a way to do this with functions.  See my answer for a way to do it without using a function at all.

Comment: @BrenBarn It is, however, intentional that I ask about functions. See my comment on your answer for use-cases that do require a function as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

If `foo` is a function consisting of a single expression (i.e., can be written as a lambda), and it's a throwaway function so you don't need to save it for later, and you want to apply it to a list, don't use a function at all.  Use a list comprehension:

```
[a*b%c for a, b, c in list_of_tuples]
```

This is more clear and more concise than anything involving a `lambda` and `map`, and eliminates the need for passing arguments at all.

More generally, if your function is a one-shot throwaway, it's not that important if it uses "ugly magic numbers" as in `lambda t: t[0]*t[1]%t[2]`.  If you're willing to take time to make it look good, then you can also take time to write it as an actual function instead of cramming it into a lambda.

Comment: Good point. To be sure, I do normally prefer list comprehensions to map and filter. However, this question occured to me while I was passing a key to `max`. I figured `map` would be a simpler example for the problem statement. Now, the problem with `max` is that it uses `reduce`, which doesn't translate nicely into a list comprehension. (Do correct me if I'm wrong!)

Comment: indeed in this particular case, comprehension is much better

Comment: I change my mind about max, sort, or any function that takes a key as an argument. You could just use a list comprehension to apply the key, then call the function without passing a key. That doesn't say much for reduce itself, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, `lambda` is no different from any other function, e.g.:

```
lambda *args: pprint.pprint(args)
lambda *args: foo(args[0], args[7], args[-1])
```

and conversely:

```
l1 = lambda a, b, c: ...
l1(*range(3))
```

in addition, `functools` provides for partial evlauation:

```
import functools
foo = lambda a, b, c, d: None
part = functools.partial(foo, 1, 2)
part(3, 4)
```

Comment: I think the OP knows this. He would like to know if this can be done automatically, if he applies a list of tuple over a lambda function. the tuples should be unpacked and applied over the lambda.

Comment: You couldn't use l1 that way if you were passing it to a function like map or filter, or passing it as the key to sort or max.

Comment: Yes I see now what OP had in mind. Uhm... let's say `explicit is better than implicit` though, let me edit in unpacking.

Comment: Well, wouldn't be using java in place of python if that were a hard and fast rule? Sometimes, explicitness introduces needless verbosity, which is distracting.

Comment: Maybe `simple is better` is the principle to apply here?